# cannot build ehealth-connector in maven or eclipse

Tags: java, maven

Can anyone please help me build ehealth-connector project? I am try to build using Maven and IDE directlym, but cannot build in both, tried both release and snapshot version

mostly targetting api-java project from the suite

https://gitlab.com/ehealth-connector

https://sourceforge.net/p/ehealthconnector/wiki/Building%20the%20eHealth%20Connector/

Comment: can you explain what you have done so far and what are the issues you faced ?

Comment: i added the dependencies in pom.xml as documented and right clicked on the project to update maven. The progress bar reaches half way but never completes. I tried to go “mvn clean install” on command line and got the following error

Comment: ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ihe: Could not resolve dependencies fo r project org.philips.ibe:ihe:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.ehealth_connector.communication:ehealth_connector-communication-ch:jar:1 .3.0-201604: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.ehealth_connector.commun ication:ehealth_connector-communication-ch:jar:1.3.0-201604

Comment: Could not transfer artifact org.ehealth_connector.communication:ehealth_connector-communication-ch: pom:1.3.0-201604 from/to projects.suisse-open-exchange.healthcare-rel (https://p rojects.suisse-open-exchange.healthcare/artifactory/releases): Access denied to: https://projects.suisse-open-exchange.healthcare/artifactory/releases/org/eheal th_connector/communication/ehealth_connector-communication-ch/1.3.0-201604/eheal th_connector-communication-ch-1.3.0-201604.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/ehealth-connector/api-java

You can find the build dependencies on the wiki page